# Swift wrong compile error: default label can only appear in switch statement

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8-beta4

`NSFileManager` has been renamed to FileManager in `Swift 2.3` onwards. So do the 
`defaultManager` class method which now just `default`
However when I use.

```
FileManager.default()
```

Compiler mis-icntepret and throw error.

> default label can only appear in switch statement

Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 beta 3

Comment: Tried using a selector and one of the performSelector methods?  Or maybe a closure?

Comment: Should be `'default'()` I guess even though autocomplete put the `default()`. Its beta.

Comment: As mentioned in the below answer. you should use." ` " not " ' " in order to escape keyword. Anyone know how to write this in a comment avoiding the formatting?

Comment: @MadNik you use the `<code>` tag to surround a backslash and the backtick.

Comment: Some of the swift 3 APIs replace the class method for the shared instance with a property.  I don't have the API in front of me by try to verify the current status of the method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Swift 2.3, but I think the syntax for escaping a keyword hasn't changed. After all, it's not a major update.

You can use the `` ` `` character to escape a keyword so as to use the keyword as an identifier for a variable, method or something else. So you can do this do create a variable named `var`:

```
var `var` = 0
```

So if you just write:

```
FileManager.`default`()
```

it should work.

btw I just looked up `NSFileManager` in the docs. And I found that there is no `default()` method. Is the docs outdated or something?

[image]

Comment: It is there if we check the source. Not updated the documentation yet though.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed in Swift 3, and the backticks are no longer necessary. Note that the default manager is now a class property rather than a class method. So the correct syntax is:

```
 FileManager.default
```